# Assign people to monthly groups without repeating

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem for which I'm not sure there is a simple answer...

I have some number of captains (right now it's 11, but could change) that organize monthly meetings of members of an organization. The members of the organization are categorized into 1 of ~14 networks.

I'm tasked with writing a scheduler of sorts that fits members into groups with 1 captain such that:

1. No 2 members of the same network is ever in a group
2. No 2 members participate in the same meeting for 3 months.
3. I need to minimize the number of unassigned members, as they will be assigned manually as the admin sees fit.

Right now I'm trying a randomized brute force method that essentially generates the groups randomly, checks for repeats over last month and the month prior, and kicks out the bad matrix if it finds one and regenerates. I made it iterate over several thousand times and it's pretty much impossible for the randomized brute force method to work in any sort of reasonable amount of time.

I'd like some sort of algorithm that could fail gracefully in that if it's mathematically impossible for the rules to be followed 100%, it still generates a matrix with as few "errors" as possible.

I've look at the [Round-Robin Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm), but it appears that's only good for groups of 2.

I think the thing that makes this more difficult is there's a small number of participants (67) compared to the number of captains and networks.

I'm not necessarily asking for code to do this, but more the types of algorithms that could handle something like this.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Maybe reading about Constraint Satisfaction Problems will help. One place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem